# Get Full Version of My Own Windows App

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, windows-store

Is there a way for me to install the full version of my own windows app from the windows store without paying for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, there are no store codes or anything like that. You will have to just side load the app.